# How to update values in chrome cache and auto-fill

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

number of websites i'm using changed their domain name, and chrome auto-fill suggests links to the URL with the old domain. how can I update all links in chrome's auto-fill / cache?

Comment: It's not auto-fill, it's omnibar. Why did you add the extension tag?

Comment: I want to edit the suggestions that are based on my browsing history. perhaps there is an extension for that or an api for listing the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to edit existing history items, so your only solution would be removing offending URLs from history.

Sadly, there is currently a [nasty bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395955) preventing this from reliably working with extension API if Chrome Sync is used.

In case you happen not to use Chrome Sync, you can write a simple extension to invoke [`chrome.history.deleteUrl`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-deleteUrl). Otherwise, you'll have to do it manually.